# How to add captcha to WordPress admin login form without plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to add a simple math captcha to the WordPress admin login form without using the plugin. I have an idea to add some action in functions.php, but I am not getting in any browser. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the admin login screen is handled by the wp-login.php file so you could modify the code in that to include the captcha but modifying wp-login.php is not advisable.